# Are "in that", "that in which" and "there" synonymous?

Tags: meaning

> A liar claimed he had courage, it was there that he was deficient.
>
> A liar claimed he had courage, it was in that he was deficient.
>
> A liar claimed he had courage, it was that in which he was deficient.

It seems that "in that", "that in which" and "there" are synonymous, especially in the above sentences. Is this true? Are there other phrasing that might be synonymous? I thought about "in which", but it's not synonymous to "in that", because "that" is a regular pronoun while "which" is a relative pronoun in "in which".

Comment: Did you create these sentences or get them from somewhere? What's the original meaning - is it something like "a liar claimed he had courage but he was actually deficient in courage" (so he was lying when he said that) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the three sentences makes much sense: a liar was deficient in courage, or in claiming he had courage?

Anyway, one thing is certain: the sentences are wrongly punctuated with that comma between two independent clauses.

Focusing on the question, the second sentence lacks a second "that":

- A liar claimed he had courage. It was there that he was deficient.
- A liar claimed he had courage. It was in that **that** he was deficient.
- A liar claimed he had courage. It was that in which he was deficient.

Comment: Another correction (rather than adding a period and a capital letter) is to simply replace the comma with a semicolon (;).

Comment: Or a colon, if seventyeightist's interpretation (which seems plausible) is correct.

Comment: Very true.  In literature, I’d say that either a colon or semicolon is more likely to be found, than having the thought split into two sentences.

Comment: How about "Prostetnic Vogon Jeltz was a fairly typical Vogon in that he was thoroughly vile."?

Comment: @Zhang That is a different structure. In the sentences further above (e.g. It was in that that he was deficient), "that" is a demonstrative: it was in that area/aspect that he was deficient. In the sentence you wrote, "that" is a conjunction introducing a noun clause: He was a typical Vogon in that he was thouroughly vile = He was a typical Vogon in this respect.

Comment: @Gustavson, Thanks! After that I looked up "in that", and found out it's a phrase, "for the reason that (used to specify the respect in which a statement is true)." Something like "because of". And another explanation, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20that